# Paradox: Query without locking the database file

Tags: .net, paradox

I'm trying to query an existing Paradox database that a third-party application populates.  My application is now blocking the third-party app and I'm wondering if there are any "query hints" or connection string properties that will query/open the database without blocking.

The database is queried using ".NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC" connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you follow the standard .NET 'disconnected' pattern (you should, close every connection asap) you are probably still keeping a connection open doue to the default connection pooling. To test that you should clear the ConnectionPool after you execute a query.

As far as I can tell, for ODBC it should be:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.ReleaseObjectPool()
```

Comment: I'm testing this out today.  Thanks for the reply.